# How can I let aws cli command wait until the update finish?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using aws cli command to update a lambda' configuration, e.g. `update memory size`. The command finishes very quick but the next command which updates the same lambda failed with:

```
An error occurred (ResourceConflictException) when calling the UpdateFunctionConfiguration 
operation: The operation cannot be performed at this time. An update is in progress for 
resource: arn:aws:lambda
```

I see there is an update request in progress which causes the command fail. Is there a way to make my aws cli command waiting until the update finish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`function-updated`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/wait/function-updated.html) command between the two function update commands. It will wait until the Lambda's `LastUpdateStatus` will be successful, meaning that the next update can be invoked.

Invoke it like so:

```
aws lambda wait function-updated --function-name $MY_FUNC
```